# change text of textarea in qml file with c++

Tags: c++, qt, text, qml

Hi,

i'm trying to make a application in QT which calculates something and output that in a specified text area.

how can i achieve that, that i can change the text when user presses on the mousearea. I've got already the following code:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include <QGraphicsObject>

#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include "eigen_function_header.h"

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
    qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("com.myself", 1, 0, "MyObject");

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/tw_looptijden_berekenen/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app->exec();
}
```

eigen_function_header.h

```
#ifndef EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H
#define EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H

#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyObject (QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
   Q_INVOKABLE int reken_tijden_uit(){

//        tekst_gebied
        return 1;
   }
};

#endif // EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.myself 1.0

Rectangle {

width: 360
height: 360
Text {
    id: tekst_gebied
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
MyObject {
   id: myobject
}

MouseArea {
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 360
    height: 251
    anchors.rightMargin: 0
    anchors.bottomMargin: 109
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.topMargin: 0
    z: 1
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        console.log(myobject.reken_tijden_uit());

    }
}

Text {
    id: text1
    x: 96
    y: 305
    text: qsTr("text")
    font.pixelSize: 12
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MouseArea {
[...]
    onClicked: {
        tekst_gebied.text = "some text"
    }
}
```

Comment: true, but i need to do a couple of math and with the output of that change the textarea

Comment: So? Do whatever you have to in OnClicked, then just assign the result to "tekst_gebied.text"

Comment: if you want to call c++ function from QML to do the math or other processing this link will help, http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/04/signal-slot-connection-with-qml-and-qt.html